# i am getting an dependency resolution error but i'm not able to fix this

Tags: java, android

**here is the error**

Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-25.3.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-25.3.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-25.3.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-25.3.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-25.3.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-25.3.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-25.3.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1 found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-25.3.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-25.3.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-25.3.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1)

app build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'

}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  // Google Services plugin


android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.phonematch"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    //Google Firestore
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.2.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'

    //----
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    implementation 'com.lorentzos.swipecards:library:1.0.9'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.0'
    //navigation
    implementation 'com.github.ittianyu:BottomNavigationViewEx:1.2.4'

    //Circle ImageView
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation "com.github.dimorinny:show-case-card-view:0.0.1"

    implementation 'com.github.BakerJQ:Android-InfiniteCards:1.0.5'
}
```

Comment: you are using the same library twice.
one in the libs folder and another one imported through dependencies,  so remove any one of them and try. it will work

Comment: `android.useAndroidX=true` and `android.enableJetifier=true` in gradle.properties

Comment: and provide a version to this api `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add these two lines in your gradle.Proparties

```
android.useAndroidX=true 
android.enableJetifier=true
```